# How to pass raw json body as parameter in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, discord

I am working on Php and trying integrate "Discord" with php,Right now i am trying to get "response" from "discrod",I tried with following code but i am confused about "$body"(raw json body),what should i pass in this parameter for get response ?Here is my current code

```
public function authorize(array $headers, string $body, string $discord_public): array
{
    $res = [
        'code' => 200,
        'payload' => []
    ];

    if (!isset($headers['x-signature-ed25519']) || !isset($headers['x-signature-timestamp'])) {
        $res['code'] = 401;
        return $res;
    }

    $signature = $headers['x-signature-ed25519'];
    $timestamp = $headers['x-signature-timestamp'];

    if (!trim($signature, '0..9A..Fa..f') == '') {
        $res['code'] = 401;
        return $res;
    }

    $message = $timestamp . $body;
    $binary_signature = sodium_hex2bin($signature);
    $binary_key = sodium_hex2bin($discord_public);

    if (!sodium_crypto_sign_verify_detached($binary_signature, $message, $binary_key)) {
        $res['code'] = 401;
        return $res;
    }

    $payload = json_decode($body, true);
    switch ($payload['type']) {
        case 1:
            $res['payload']['type'] = 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            $res['payload']['type'] = 2;
            break;

        default:
            $res['code'] = 400;
            return $res;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What have you tried as `$body`?

Comment: @JacobMulquin: i am getting "NULL" value, i saw following link for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692328/how-to-verify-discord-endpoint-using-php